# Android 4.3.1 : Touchscreen not responding on return from sleep / or after call's end

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean

My phone has Android 4.3.1.

Sometimes, when it returns from sleep, or at the end of a phone call, the touchscreen does not respond. I have to press the power button several times to make the touch screen responsive. In the worst case, I have to remove the battery and turn it on again.

What can I do to resolve this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: Which device is this? Do you see a black screen when trying to return it from sleep or after ending a call, or you see the screen as it usually appears but it doesn't respond? The former is a case I've heard of, so I'm asking for confirmation.

Comment: No , the screen is as usually , just doesn't respond

Answer (score -1):

Yes !.... woke my nexus 7 after being in sleep mode all night and it fired up perfectly with no dodgy touch screen issues at all.
Could it be that simple that Chrome browser was causing the problems all along ?

another bonus is using Opera Browser.... after being a die-hard fan of Chrome for many years on my desktop PC, it was a very slight learning curve to master Opera.
It's running so smooth and quick !

Comment: Please post multiple answers only when the content differs widely. That is not the case here. Note that you can always edit your own post. Consider deleting this one and [edit](http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/127627/edit) the earlier one.